# Modify IntelliJ javadoc template

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

Is there a way to modify the template IntelliJ uses for a method's Javadoc?

In particular, I want my javadoc comments to look like this:

```
/********************
 * 
 *  Comment here
 *
 *********************/
```

However, when I reformat the code, the javadoc ends up looking like this:

```
/**
 * ******************
 * 
 *  Comment here
 *
    ********************
 */
```

Comment: A javadoc comment must start with /**.  Does that mean it cannot start with /*********************?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't seem like you want JavaDoc comments then, as they are defined to look like how IntelliJ is making them.

- [Format of a Doc Comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format)
- [Structure of a JavaDoc comment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc#Structure_of_a_Javadoc_comment)

You can disable JavaDoc formatting:

1. Settings > Project Settings > Code Style > JavaDoc
2. Uncheck `Enable JavaDoc formatting`

This way, you can have your multi-line comments not get reformatted as JavaDoc comments.
IntelliJ is identifying them (correctly) as JavaDoc comments since they have two asterisks.

You can also change them to regular multi-line comments (not JavaDoc comments) by adding a space before the second asterisk (e.g. `/* ****************`), which should also have IntelliJ not reformat them.